# vue page reload function - errpr

Tags: vuejs2, vue-router

I want to build a simple function which forwards the browser to a specific destination if the route.name is Idx and if not, reloads the page. I use the following code and get the following error

I use vue 2-x.

**Code**

```
reloadPage() {
    if (this.$route.name == "Idx") {
        this.$router.push('/')
        //console.log("test")
    } else {
        this.$router.go() // RELOAD THE PAGE TO OVERTAKE THE CHANGES
    }            
}
```

**error**

> Uncaught (in promise) NavigationDuplicated: Avoided redundant
> navigation to current location: "/idx".

This error only appears when I run the function in the /idx site.

What do I miss?

Thanks!

Comment: `window.location.reload();`

Comment: Hey Adam, thanks but if I replace the this.$router.go() with window.location.reload(); the page doesn't reload at all.... It works when I put the this.$router.go() in an extra function but that's not nice to look at

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your application didnot break with this error, one solution that i can think of is to handle the promise.

```
reloadPage() {
if (this.$route.name == "Idx") {
    this.$router.push('/').catch(()=>{});
    
} else {
    this.$router.go() // RELOAD THE PAGE TO OVERTAKE THE CHANGES
}
```

}

Also, i tried running the same logic in the vue3 and didnt encounter this exception, i think they get rid of the same route navigation.

```
confirmInput() {
  // do something
  console.log('test', this.$router.currentRoute.value.path);
  if (this.$router.currentRoute.value.path === '/myroute') {
    this.$router.push('/');
  } else {
    this.$router.go();
  }
},
```

Comment: Thanks Ruben, the first answer worked for me and I will keep the second solution in mind since I will switch to vue3 soon.